# ggplot geom_point colour based on multiple factors

Tags: r, ggplot2, scale-color-manual

I have a dataframe where I am trying to plot the points and separate them based on colour. I can successfully do this if I just set general boundaries like values = c("(-Inf,1]" = "green",
"(1,2]" = "red",
"(2, Inf]" = "black")) +

```
CTD <- c(3, 3,  3,  3,  3,  5,  5,  5,  7,  7,  7,  7,  12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 9,  9,  9,  9,  9,  19, 19, 19, 19, 20, 20, 20, 20, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21)
Depth <- c(10,  30, 40, 50, 80, 10, 20, 50, 5,  20, 50, 100,    7,  15, 50, 70, 100,    7,  10, 20, 50, 70, 7,  20, 50, 70, 100,    5,  20, 40, 90, 5,  25, 70, 120,    5,  20, 40, 60, 90)
CN <- c(9.283378839,    6.346533977,    3.75246344, 5.096343091,    5.465256863,    5.424842029,    5.053200886,    1.582119456,    6.20074949, 5.79160957, 6.229882574,    2.419344034,    4.909357185,    3.93951578, 3.700415644,    2.374574914,    2.528295309,    0.825305752,    0.895049775,    2.63447744, 1.081411857,    1.26984798, 4.944151635,    4.346435626,    2.974542787,    2.574266373,    3.043154784,    3.32420804, 3.084480732,    1.576270571,    0.791589174,    3.888050262,    2.177251093,    1.627385084,    2.433798779,    3.097900,   2.749822293,    2.827167853,    1.723315947,    1.207824117)
data <- as.data.frame(CTD, Depth, CN)

(data <- ggplot(data=data, aes(x=CN, y=Depth, group=CTD)) + 
geom_point(aes(colour = cut(CN, c(-Inf, 1, 2, Inf))),
           size = 0.8) +
scale_color_manual(name = "CN",
                   values = c("(-Inf,1]" = "green",
                                            "(1,2]" = "red",
                                            "(2, Inf]" = "black")) +
geom_path(colour="grey", size=0.3) + 
 scale_y_reverse() + 
theme_bw() + 
scale_x_continuous(position = "top") +
theme(plot.background = element_blank(),
      panel.grid.major = element_blank() ,
      panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
      axis.text = element_text(color = 'black', size=10),
      text = element_text(size=10)))
```

But there are a few values that are between 1 and 2 that need to be in black and a value of 2.6 that needs to be in red. So this is outside the limits set above.

I tried to be more specific like below but only the black points show up and not the red or green dots anymore. Is there a way where I can get these specific dots to be in red and green and anything other than this in black?

```
  scale_color_manual(name = "CN",
                  values = c("(1.58]" = "red",
                              "(0.82]" = "green",
                             "(0.89]" = "green",
                              "(2.63]" = "red",
                             "(1.08]" = "red",
                             "(1.26]" = "red",
                             "(1.57]" = "red",
                             "(0.79]" = "green",
                             "(1.2]" = "red",
                              "(2, Inf]" = "black")) +
```

Comment: You should define a new group variable according to how you want to color and assign color=newgroup in the aes in geom_point.

Comment: You have only 3 groups in `colour` using `cut` but in `scale_color_manual` you define lot more groups.

Comment: If I add   geom_point(aes(colour = cut(CN, c(1,58, 0.82, 0.89, 2.63, 1.08, 1.26, 1.57, 0.79, 1.2, 2, Inf))),
then there are no points in the entire plot... and if I remove the 'cut' command then all the points are black...

Comment: @YBS is it possible to define a new group variable just using these values and anything else gets black? I can't seem to find a solution online because the data here is just for one site and all the other sites (not included in the example here) just have black points so if I have to type in every single CN for all the sites then its not feasible as there are too many...

Answer (score 1):

For specific colors for outliers, you need to transform your data to show the required color. Using your sample data, try this

```
data1 <- data.frame(CTD, Depth, CN)
  data2 <- data1 %>% mutate(mycolor1 = case_when(CN<=1 ~ "green", CN>2 ~ "black", CN>1 ~ "red"))
  wantred <- c(2.63447744,3.097900)
  wantblack <- c(1.081411857, 1.26984798, 1.723315947)
  data <- transform(data2, mycolor2 = ifelse(CN %in% wantred, "red", mycolor1)) %>% 
            mutate(mycolor = ifelse(CN %in% wantblack, "black", mycolor2) )
  
  p <- ggplot(data=data, aes(x=CN, y=Depth, group=CTD)) + 
      geom_point(aes(color=mycolor))+
      scale_color_manual(name = "CN", breaks=unique(data$mycolor), values=unique(data$mycolor)) +
      geom_path(colour="grey", size=0.3) + 
      scale_y_reverse() + 
      theme_bw() + 
      scale_x_continuous(position = "top") +
      theme(plot.background = element_blank(),
            panel.grid.major = element_blank() ,
            panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
            axis.text = element_text(color = 'black', size=10),
            text = element_text(size=10))
 p
```

output

[image]

Comment: yes this is the same as my first attempt above. The problem is that I have 1 value (2.6) that needs to be red (and instead is coming out black) and one in the 1 - 2 range that need to be black but is coming out red...

Comment: Please see the updated code and output. You can choose whichever points you want to make red or black in the vectors wantred and wantblack.